# I'm making a form with login/password through Firebase. When I click on Login with the email and password registered in Firebase, I get this return:

Tags: vite

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' (at content.js:16:41)
chunk-GZ55BCQ2.js?v=15bbc095:521 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of .
at a
at a
at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=c31e98c5:4757:5)
at div
at form
at div
at Signin (http://localhost:5173/src/assets/components/signin/Signin.jsx?t=1708559671856:28:29)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=c31e98c5:3537:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=c31e98c5:3972:5)
at AppRoutes
at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=c31e98c5:3915:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=c31e98c5:4655:5)
at index

I believe this is what is preventing the application from loading the home after authentication